# xargs and < and > to the same files

Tags: shell, io-redirection, xargs

I want to run `git stripspace` on all my source code files, on each build (or precommit or just manually), to remove extraneous whitespace, and later maybe to format the code in a standard way,

So I want to do something like

```
git stripspace < project/code.m > project/code.m
```

so I thought I should be able to use `find -exec` or `xargs` but by the looks of `find` does not like 'git stripspace' (maybe because of the space in between or the < or >) and I don't know how to pass the same file name, same argument, twice in a row with the proper redirections (< >) .

Comment: **DO NOT DO THIS**. Because of the way the shell interprets the command sequences, it'll empty `project/code.m` first to prepare the output pipe from the `>` before it tries to read it.

Comment: I see the concept that would be applicable from the duplicate suggested but it doesn't directly address the question here though.  I think the chosen answer is very straight-forward and can be a good reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're clobbering the file before you read from it. You need to use a temporary file or a utility like `sponge` from [moreutils](http://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/).

You can't use `find -exec` or `xargs` in this case. You would need to pass a shell a single argument containing both the commands and the file name. `xargs` and `find` expect the file name marker (which they replace with the file name) to be a standalone argument. You can use a loop instead.

With a temporary file:

```
find | while read file ; do
    git stripspace < "$file" > tempfile
    mv -f tempfile "$file"
done
```

With `sponge`:

```
find | while read file ; do
    git stripspace < "$file" | sponge "$file"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Vim in Ex mode:

```sh
ex -sc '%!git stripspace' -cx project/code.m
```

1. `%` select all lines
2. `!` run command
3. `x` save and close